# what exactly new {} doing in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#

i was going through a code and found following lines of code i was unable to understand...

```
objDashBoardHierarchyInfo = SubscribeList.GroupBy(x = > new {
    ReportID = x.ReportId, ReportName = x.ReportName, Direction = x.DisplayColumn
})
    .Select(x = > new DashBoardHierarchyInfo {
    ReportID = x.Key.ReportID,
    ReportName = x.Key.ReportName,
    DisplayDirection = x.Key.Direction ? ? 0,
    oListDashBoardReportInfo = x.Select(c = > new DashBoardReportInfo {
        DataSourceObjectName = c.DataSourceObjectName,
        ReportSubType = c.OutputType,
        DataSourceId = c.DataSourceId,
        XvalueFeild = "",
        YvalueFeild = "",
        ReportName = c.ReportName,
        BodyId = c.BodyID,
        ReportID = c.ReportId,
        UserDashboardReportId = c.UserDashboardReportId,
        ChartTypeID = c.ChartTypeID,
        SeriesColor = c.Color,
        SeriesControlTypeId = c.ControlType ? ? 0
    }).ToList < DashBoardReportInfo > ()
}).ToList < DashBoardHierarchyInfo > ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `new { }` create an anonymous type for you and also create object of that anonymous type that is returned. You can read more about anonymous type on this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

The statement you are asking about create object of anonymous type using the `SubscribeList` object being pass through `lambda`.

```
new { ReportID = x.ReportId, ReportName = x.ReportName, Direction = x.DisplayColumn }
```

You can create object of anonymous type without lamda as show under.

```
var myObj = new {Id=1, Name="abc"};
Console.WriteLine(myObj.Id);
Console.WriteLine(myObj.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`new {  }` syntax creates instance of [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb397696.aspx).

```
new { ReportID = x.ReportId, ReportName = x.ReportName, Direction = x.DisplayColumn }
```

means that I want to group this list by every possible combination of three properties `ReportID`, `ReportName`, `DisplayColumn`.